# Priority Queue  not maintaing queue property

Tags: java, android

I  Have made a prority blocking queue.Inserting is properly done based on priority.when i delete the head of the queue,last element of the queue becomes the head of the queue ,procedure repeats.
Suppose i inserted 123456789 in the queue.

```
First deleted : 1;  queue elements :92345678  
Second deleted:  9; queue elements :8234567
```

and so on.

I need to achieve queue property, which is not being maintained.

i.e 
First delete : 1 queue elements :23456789
Second delete :2 queue elements :3456789

```
package com.block.ui;

import java.util.Iterator;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class PriorityBlockQueSamplActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

EditText et;
EditText et2;
Button b1;
Button b2;

Controller c ;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    et=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    et2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    b1 =(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b2 =(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    c= new Controller();


    Message m = new Message();
    m.mPriority=1;
    m.Subject="1";
    c.insert(m);

    Message n = new Message();
    n.mPriority=1;
    n.Subject="2";
    c.insert(n);
    Message p = new Message();
    p.mPriority=1;
    p.Subject="3";
    c.insert(p);

    Message q = new Message();
    q.mPriority=1;
    q.Subject="4";
    c.insert(q);


    b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Iterator<Message> iter = c.getQueue().iterator();
            while(iter.hasNext()){
                Message m =iter.next();
                Log.i("MESSAGE", "Element "+m.Subject+" priority :"+m.mPriority);
            }

        }
    });
    b2.setOnClickListener(new  OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Message m=c.getMessage();
            c.delete(m);

        }
    });
}
```

}

and one more class

```
 `public class Controller {

private int queueSize=300;
Comparator<Message> comparator = new PriorityComaparator();
PriorityBlockingQueue<Message> qu = new PriorityBlockingQueue<Message>(queueSize,comparator);

            public Controller() {

}

public void insert(Message msg) {

    boolean status = qu.add(msg);
    if (status)
        log("Added successfully " + msg.Subject + " priority "
                + msg.mPriority + " size :" + qu.size());
    else
        log("Failed to add " + msg.Subject + " with priority "
                + msg.mPriority);

}

public void delete(Message msg) {
    if (qu.contains(msg)) {
        boolean status = qu.remove(msg);
        if (status)
            log("deleted successfully " + msg.Subject + " priority " + msg.mPriority
                    + " size :" + qu.size());
        else
            log("Failed to delete " + msg.Subject + " with priority "+ msg.mPriority);
    }
}

public Message getMessage() {
    return qu.peek(); 
}

public PriorityBlockingQueue<Message> getQueue(){
    return qu;
}
void log(String msg) {
    Log.i("QUEUE", msg);
}

class PriorityComaparator implements Comparator<Message> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Message m, Message n) {
        int y = ((Message) m).mPriority; // 1 -highest 3-least
        int z = ((Message) n).mPriority;


        if (y < z) {
            return -1;
        }
        if (y > z) {
            return 1;
            }
            return 0;
            }

        }

}`
```

Comment: *Why* do you move the last element into the head of the queue?

Comment: this is what i see  when i delete the element in the queue

Comment: We'd probably have to see some code.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever code updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the priority queue you are using is your personal implementation, then try to an **heap** data structure.

As the wikipage says:

> The heap is one maximally efficient implementation of an abstract data type called a priority queue.

Here is the link to the [page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_%28data_structure%29).

Remember that in Java you don't need to implement it, you can use the standard [PriorityQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) class or [PriorityBlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/PriorityBlockingQueue.html) if you need that it works in a multithread program.

Comment: shdn't i use priorityBlockingQueue ?

Comment: priorityBlockingQueue or PriorityQueue  are same except synchronised..      My prob is deleting an element from the queue is not in order what we generally expect  @dash1e

Comment: Yes you can use PriorityBlockingQueue if you need synchronization between many threads.

Comment: Are you saying that Java PriorityQueue bugs when you delete an Item?

Comment: in the queue  when same priority messages left, the delete order is like LIFO, which should not be the case in queues...

Answer (score 2):

If, as in your sample, all inserted elements have the *same* priority, then the retrieval order isn't well defined. From [PriorityQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) (from which [PriorityBlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/PriorityBlockingQueue.html) derives the same ordering rules):

> The head of this queue is the least element with respect to the specified ordering. If multiple elements are tied for least value, the head is one of those elements -- **ties are broken arbitrarily.**

(Emphasis added)

Comment: so, i can acheive normal queue property in this case..!

Comment: @meher - you could add enqueuedTime to `Message`, set it during insert, and use it in your comparator to break ties between two messages with the same priority. (Or, introduce a wrapper class if you're unable to modify `Message` directly).

Comment: @ Damien_The_Unbeliever first point was in mind and  introducing wrapper class ,how it is possible,can u explain me clearly..